# Blender project has gone blank

Tags: rendering

I was working on a project and I saved it and closed blender and I reopen it to find this[image: blank canvas]

is this a common thing to happen? is it my computer? anyone have a clue on how to get my project back? this is a screenshot
[image: project]

Comment: If you haven't closed blender again yet, you could try File > Recover > Last Session. It's hard to tell without knowing more about your project. Did you create the mountains using displacement in Cycles, and somehow switched to EEVEE so the displacement is not showing? Is your camera inside an object? Are the objects in the outliner the same now as they were in your project?

Comment: I think your scene just went back to solid shading. Click on the rightmost sphere-like icon in the top right of your 3D viewport to enable rendered view